# What is the probability that each element in this string is non-zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Question:** You are given two bitstrings a1, a2, .. a77 and b1, b2, .. b77 of length 77 In both bitstrings, each bit is 0 with **probability 3/4**, and 1 with **probability 1/4** (independent of all other bits).

Consider the string: a1-b1, a2-b2, ..., a77-b77.

What is the probability that each element in this string is non-zero?

**Answer: 1.586381421*10^-33**

**Attempt:**

Non-zero probability is 1/4 for both bitstrings.
If both bitstrings are subtracted by one another for length 77, then it shouldn't it be (1/4)*(1/4) = 1/16 be the probability of the new string being non-zero

Total number of possible bitstrings = 2^77

Probability: 1/16/2^77 = 4.13*10^-25

Comment: $a_1-b_1\neq 0$ just means that $a_1\neq b_1$.  It certainly does not mean that both of the elements are $1$.  Also, while it is true that there are $2^{77}$ possible strings, they are not equi-probable so you can't use that as a denominator in the way you have.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: As a suggestion:  start with a shorter string.  What is the probability if both strings have length $1$?  Length $2$?  Length $3$?

Comment: @lulu Isn't the question basically asking to find the probability of each element being non-zero so meaning it has to be 1? Bitstrings have either 0 or 1, so according to this, non-zero bitstrings = bitstrings with only 1s?

Comment: No.  The difference is not itself a bit string.  if $a_1=0,b_1=1$ then $a_1-b_1=-1$ which is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_i=a_i-b_i$. You need to find $$P[c_1 \neq 0, c_2 \neq 0, \ldots, c_{77} \neq 0] = p^{77}$$

where $$p=P[c_i \neq 0] = P[a_i = 0, b_i = 1] + P[a_i = 1, b_i = 0] = 2\times\frac{3}{16}=\frac{6}{16}=\frac{3}{8}$$

So, the final answer is $$\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^{77}$$ which gives the answer you provided.

Comment: Why is p to the power 77? Also, why does ai and bi have to be pairs of (0,1) and (1,0)? Is it to satisfy the ai - bi != 0 equation?

Comment: It's $p^{77}$ because the individual elements $\{c_i\}$ are independent (because $\{a_i\} \text{ and }\{b_i\}$ are independent). Yes, $c_i\neq 0$ only if $a_i\neq b_i$, so, you need to consider the cases where this holds. Note that $c_i\neq 0$ means that $c_i = 1$ or $c_i = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

$a_i-b_i\neq0\implies a_i\neq b_i$

The possible pairs $(a_i, b_i)$ are $(0, 1)$ and $(1,0)$, with each pair having a probability $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$. Therefore, the total probability is $(\frac{3}{16}+\frac{3}{16})^{77}=(\frac{6}{16})^{77}$.

Comment: why does the probability have to be to the power 77?

Comment: Because you have $77$ pairs of corresponding bits $(a_i, b_i)$, and the probability that the difference $a_i-b_i\neq0$ is $6/16$ for all pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $(\frac{6}{16})^{77}$.
One digit i being 0 is equivalent to $\lnot(a_i=b_i=0\lor a_i=b_i=1)$

Comment: can you please elaborate on how you got the answer. I don't follow your logic